# AngularJS directives, templates and ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am trying to create a directive that has an **ng-include** in it.
The directive currently looks like this:

```
.directive('kdTest', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            kit: '=kdTest',
            garment: '=kdGarment'
        },
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.kit);
            console.log(scope.garment);
        }
    }
});
```

what I want to do is change the template to look more like this:

```
.directive('kdTest', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            kit: '=kdTest',
            garment: '=kdGarment'
        },
        template: '<div ng-include="'/assets/garments/' + garment.slug + '.svg'"></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.kit);
            console.log(scope.garment);
        }
    }
});
```

but as you can see, the single quotes are going to cause me problems.
Can someone help me fix that?

Also, I need to be able to access the **svg** element from inside the directive.

**Update 1**

So, I have changed my directive to this:

```
.directive('kdTest', function () {
    var colours,
        design,
        garment;

    // Function to show our selected design
    var showDesign = function (element) {

        // Get our image
        var svg = element.find('svg');

        console.log(svg.length);

        // If we have an image
        if (svg.length) {

            ///-- removed for brevity --//
        }
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            kit: '=kdTest',
            garment: '=kdGarment'
        },
        template: '<div ng-include="svgPath"></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            // Attach our scope to our global variables
            colours = scope.colours;
            design = scope.design;
            garment = scope.garment;

            // Create our svgPath
            scope.svgPath = 'assets/garments/' + scope.garment.slug + '.svg';

            // Show our selected design
            showDesign(element);
        }
    }
});
```

So in my function **showDesign** the console.log(svg.length) returns 0.
How can I get it to actually see the svg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-include` includes the content asyncronously, and so when the `link` function of the directive runs, the DOM elements of the `ng-include` (incl. `svg`) are still not there.

Luckily, `ng-include` provides an `onload` event, and so you could do:

```
template: '<div ng-include="svgPath" onload="svgLoaded()"></div>',
link: function(scope, element){
   // rest of your link function...

   scope.svgLoaded = function(){
     // Show our selected design
     showDesign(element);
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** (to complete the answer):

the inner quotes should be escaped (as suggested in another answer), like so:

```
ng-include="\'/some/path\'"
```

or, better - the path could be constructed in the `link` function and the variable assigned to `ng-include`.

Answer (score 3):

Simple. Escape the quotes.

Replace:

```
template: '<div ng-include="'/assets/garments/' + garment.slug + '.svg'"></div>',
```

With:

```
template: '<div ng-include="\'/assets/garments/\' + garment.slug + \'.svg\'"></div>',
```

Or:

```
template: "<div ng-include=\"'/assets/garments/\' + garment.slug + '.svg'\"></div>',
```

---

Or better yet, just link the template to a html file:

```
templateUrl: "some/html/file.html",
```

That contains the include:

```
<div ng-include="garmentPath"></div>
```

And set the path in a variable, in the `link` function:

```
scope.garmentPath = '/assets/garments/' + scope.garment.slug + '.svg';
```

---

To access the svg element, you may want to use a html file, as I suggested.

```
<div id="mySvg" ng-include="garmentPath"></div>
```

Then you can use jQuery to get the element: `$('#mySvg svg');`
Or native JS: `document.getElementById("mySvg").getElementsByTagName("svg")`

Comment: I knew that bit was simple, you answered my first question. Can you answer the second one? I have updated my question.

Comment: @r3plica: I added a option to do that.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `templateUrl: "some/html/file.html"` instead of `template: "some/html/file.html"`?

Comment: I am not using jquery :)

Comment: Oh, whoops. The newly added line should work then, although it maybe a good idea to add some checks if `getElementById` actually returns something.

Comment: nah, that doesn't work. It just returns undefined. I assume it is somehow adding the template after the link function is run?

Comment: I have upvoted your answer because you did provide a solution to the first question and it was well written. But I have marked New Dev's answer as correct for the actual include issue :)